# Create all possible adjacency lists from another list

Tags: java, algorithm, list, sorting

I have an object Point which stores X and Y coordinate. There is a List of Point objects that looks like this:

```
(8,0),(8,1),(8,2),(8,3),(8,4),(7,4),(6,4),(5,4),(4,4),(3,4),(2,4),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(0,8),(4,5),(4,6),(3,6),(2,6),(4,3),(4,2),(4,1)
```

I want to do all the possible lists from (8,0) to (0,8) where the elements will be adjacent to each other.
For example:
list 1: `(8,0),(8,1),(8,2),(8,3),(8,4),(7,4),(6,4),(5,4),(4,4),(3,4),(2,4),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(0,8)`

list 2: (`8,0),(8,1),(8,2),(8,3),(8,4),(7,4),(6,4),(5,4),(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),(3,6),(2,6),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(0,8)`

list 3: (`8,0),(8,1),(8,2),(8,3),(8,4),(7,4),(6,4),(5,4),(4,4),(4,3),(4,2),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(3,4),(2,4),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(0,8)`

Edit: notice in list 3 that there are duplicates. This case means that there is an element that is not adjancet with anyone else, and it needs to go back until another element is adjacent to some next available element.

Take a look at point (4,1). It was stored after (4,2), and there is no (4,0)/(3,1)/(5,1), so it needs to return to (4,2), because (4,2) then have adjancet point (4,3).

Comment: Yes, this case means that it came to the end of the adjacency, and it needs to go back until another element is adjacent to some next available element. I will edit my post with this addition.

Comment: are there any limits such as how many total steps, which direction is allowed?

Comment: If duplicates are allowed, what is stopping you from going back and forth between the same two points as many times as you like? Aren't there infinitely many sequences to find, then?

Comment: There are no limits on total steps, direction is left, right, up, down. It need to go from starting point (8,0) to the destination point (0,8). In between there are several combinations of paths. It is only important that every point is adjacent to the next one in the list.

Comment: So how do you expect to find "all possible" paths, when there are infinitely many?

Comment: There are no indefinitely many. In the example I showed you, there are only three cases.

Comment: @Peter94 But you have chosen in list 3 to loop once over `(4,3),(4,2),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)`. With no limits, why have you not chosen to take that loop twice? Or seven times? Or a million? Or none? Or just `(4,3),(4,2),(4,3)`, skipping `(4,1)`?

Comment: I solved the problem so going to close the question.

Looping over (4,3),(4,2),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3) is because there is (4,1) that should be included because it is a possible cell to go through. This problem was part of one another bigger problem, but it doesnt matter. Skipping (4,1) means I can also skip (4,2). If there was no (4,1) at all then I would need in list three something like (4,3),(4,2),(4,3). Anyway, the problem solved making some adjustments on BFS algorithm